# Showing a red alert text near an input if the input does not match what we want

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I want to display some red text in a website if the content of an input is not what I want the person to put.
My input is a number and I want to check that the number is > 15.

I know how to check for that with jquery, but to show the red text I was thinking of having it already in the html with a hidden class and then removing the hidden class when the input is not correct, but it seems a bit dirty ? Is there a better way to make some text appear in that case ?

Comment: 100s of ways of doing it. That is one way

Comment: No no, there‘s no problem with your idea, just try it

Comment: HTML5 validation. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure

Comment: I haven't looked at HTML5 validation, although my inputs are not in a form but just inputs standalone

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#constraining_the_values_of_your_entries for an example of validation of min (and max) value of a number

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Without knowing what kind of input we're talking about exactly, and with no code provided, it's hard to give an exact answer for your issue. But the `pattern` attribute on forms should do the trick, when it comes to client-side validation. You can use CSS to customize your current input field, no reason to use jQuery or hidden objects.

From Mozilla:

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, lightgreen);
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or a cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" required pattern="[Bb]anana|[Cc]herry">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `pattern` attributes uses regular expressions, so you should be able to make it validate all kinds of inputs.

**EDIT:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation

> min and max: Specifies the minimum and maximum values of numerical input types

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, lightgreen);
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="choose" name="i_like" min="16">
```

Comment: Thanks that's interesting, my input is a number and I want to check that the number is > 15, can this work with the pattern attribute ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: This should be part of the question, please edit above, @Gilgamesh94

Comment: @Gilgamesh94 I've included a new example.

Comment: The form validation should be good for that yes, although I'm not using a form for now, just a input and button (and then javascript), should I absolutely use a form ? I don't want the page to refresh or redirect after clicking the button though

Comment: No. You could've tried that yourself though.

Comment: I did but when I try it without a form the minimum ammount doesn't work, I can still put  a number smaller than 15

Comment: @Gilgamesh94 But that wasn't your question.